# Is James Delaney describing the East India Company in his own words?

Tags: dialogue, taboo

During James Delaney's first negotation with the East India Company in [*Taboo*](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt3647998/) S01E01 he, upon their pressing him to sell Nootka Sound to them, tells them rather straight what he thinks about the EIC:

> The Leviathan of the Seas, is it? The terrible shadow? The beast with a million eyes, and a million ears? Conquest, rape, plunder? I studied your methods in your school, and I do know the evil that you do because I was once part of it.

But especially those first three sentences stuck out to me as rather out of place. They certainly didn't immediately seem like a genuine spontaneous saying of Delaney's. Now, the "Leviathan" part is apparently based on the sea monster of the same name from Judeo-Christian mythology and the following sentences just go with that theme. However, **is the exact phrasing he used actually taken from an existing work** (be that the bible or something else) or referencing an existing saying (maybe even one historically used to describe the not so pleaseant aspects of the EIC before?) Or is this genuinely an invention of James Delaney and the writers of the show?